# importing python modules in aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pip, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I have about 40-42 python modules to use in my lambda functions, does it mean i have to make a zip of all with my main handler.py and upload. I know about boto-3 but could not get through it as the documentation is not specific. Could someone help to find the easiest way to get around this.

Comment: What is your actual question? You have to include all dependencies (except the AWS SDK/boto3) in the zip file you upload to S3. What are you trying to ask about boto3 specifically? What are  you trying to "get around" specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (with exception of the aws-sdk) it's up to you to package and include all your modules when deploying to Lambda.

Luckily this is such a common task that there are a few good frameworks out there to help you automate this process, such as:

- Serverless Framework (with Python Requirements): https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements
- Chalice: https://github.com/aws/chalice

n.b. this isn't unique to Python- node developers have to include their node_modules, and Golang devs have to compile to a static executable.